# How to use Bootstrap Modals with Spring Boot Thymeleaf List?

Tags: spring-boot, modal-dialog, thymeleaf, bootstrap-5

I list out my users. It works perfectly, every user has their own Bootstrap card. But when I click on "more" to trigger the Modal, every "more" button gives the same Modal, which is the pop-up window for User #1. So no matter which user's data interests me, it always shows the same Modal. I want it to work properly, so that whenever I click on the more button the window pops up with that user's data.

```
    <div th:each="user : ${listUsers}" class="card mb-3">
                <div class="row g-0">
                    <!--  <div class="col-md-3">
                        <img src="/images/noimage2.png" alt="...">
                    </div>-->
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h3 class="card-title"
                                th:text="${user.name}">Name</h3>

                            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"
                                data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
                                <i class="fas fa-address-card"></i> More
                            </button>

                            <!-- Modal -->
                            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1"
                                aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div
                                    class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"
                                                th:text="${user.name}">Modal title</h5>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn-close"
                                                data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">

                                            <span class="d-inline"
                                                th:text="${user.address}"></span> | <span
                                                th:text="${user.phoneNumber}"></span> | <span
                                                th:text="${user.email}">email</span>
                                        </div>

                                        <p class="card-body"
                                            th:text="${user.description}"></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer"></div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your buttons are targetting `#exampleModal` -- you can see here:`data-bs-target="#exampleModal"`.  If you want the buttons to work, you need to give each of your modals a unique id and then target the correct modal with the correct button. So...

1. Add the [status variable](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status) onto your loop.

   ```
   <div th:each="user, status : ${listUsers}" class="card mb-3">
   ```
2. Use the `${status.index}` variable to create a unique id for your target:

   ```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"
            data-bs-toggle="modal" th:data-bs-target="|#userModal${status.index}|">
      <i class="fas fa-address-card"></i> More
    </button>
   ```
3. Use the `${status.index}` variable to create a unique id for your modal:

   ```
    <div class="modal fade" th:id="|#userModal${status.index}|" tabindex="-1"
      aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   ```

Comment: I don't even know how to thank you. I've been searching for the solution the whole day and yours solved it in a minute. Thank you very much.