# How to map jquery to each bootstrap Modal in thymeleaf?

Tags: jquery, spring, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf, bootstrap-modal

I have the following scenario,

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function (){
        $("#inputText").hide();
        $("#checkboxId").click(function (){
            $("#div1").toggle("slow");
            $("#div2").toggle("slow");
            $("#div3").toggle("slow");
            $("#div4").toggle("slow");
            $("#div5").toggle("slow");
        });
   });
```

and the page has bootstrap modal like this

```
<div th:each="item : ${itemList}" class="row mt-1" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
   <div class="col-sm-8">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
                            th:attrappend="data-target=${item.getItemName()}">Update</button>

     <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" th:attrappend="id=${item.getItemName()}">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">

                            <!-- Modal content-->
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times; 
                                     </button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" th:text="${job.getJobName()}"></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <form th:action="@{/action/__${item.getItemName()}__}" 
                                                 th:object="${timer}" method=post>
                                       <div><input type = "checkbox" id="checkboxId" 
                                             name="checkboxId/> </div>
                                       <div id="div1"><input type = "text" id="checkboxId" 
                                             name="checkboxId/> </div>
                                       <div id="div2"><input type = "text" id="checkboxId" 
                                             name="checkboxId/> </div>
                                       <div id="div3"><input type = "text" id="checkboxId" 
                                             name="checkboxId/> </div>
                                       <div id="div4"><input type = "text" id="checkboxId" 
                                             name="checkboxId/> </div
                                       <div id="div5"><input type = "text" id="checkboxId" 
                                             name="checkboxId/> </div
                                    </form>
                              </div>
                          </div>
              </div>

   </div>
```

ignore any missing closing tag

**Upon executing, server renders all item but Jquery mentioned above only works for first item [populated by thymeleaf each] after that no modals are able to use jquery.**

**Upon clicking checkbox jquery doesn't execute PLEAE HELP.**

> Tried bootstrap modal event `$("myModal").on("shown.bs.modal",function(e){})` but didn't work.

Comment: You need to have unique IDs for your elements if you are going to render them in a list.  See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66909052/4126893

Comment: Hi @Metroids thank u for the reply, as i am setting id to each model and button dynamically using "th:attrappned" (it replaces the value in id at runtime) so the population of different data works fine but i have problem only with jquery which works only on first Modal in the list and it doesn't apply on rest of the modals.

Answer (score 0):

After so much effort i finally found a solution which doesn't require any function call or server interaction here it is.

**I modified my jQuery script to below and it works perfectly fine**

```
   <script th:inline="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $("#checkBoxId").click(function (){
            var modalId = $(this).closest("div .modal").attr('id');
            $('#'+modalId).find("#div1").toggle("slow");
            $('#'+modalId).find("#ddiv2").toggle("slow");
            $('#'+modalId).find("#div3").toggle("slow");
            $('#'+modalId).find("#div4").toggle("slow");
            $('#'+modalId).find("#inputText").toggle("slow");
        });
    });
  </script>
```

To initially hide some elements and to apply toggle together with other elements you need to set

```
    .initialHiddenElementClass{
          display : none;
     }
```

In my case it was inputText.

Hope it is helpful.

PS: it is my first post.