# th:each is only displaying a single item when used with bootstrap collapse + spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I am trying to display a list via th:each, also I am using a partially-collapsible sidebar where I want to display this. Unfortunately with the current implementation it is listing only 1 item in the side bar, whereas I can list all items if I iterate it without any collapse related classes (with plain ul-li tags)

controller (AppController.java):

```
List<String> topStatDirs = getStatsModels("top.out");
model.addAttribute("topStatDirs",topStatDirs);
return "viewReport.html";
```

view (viewReport.html):

```
    <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#top_ul" data-toggle="collapse"
                        aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle"> <i
                            class="fas fa-microchip"></i> Top</a>
                        <ul  class="collapse list-unstyled" id="top_ul"  th:each="topStatDir:${topStatDirs}">
                                <a href="#"><li  class="sidebar_li_item" th:text="${topStatDir}">topStatDir</li></a>
                        </ul> 
                    </li>
                     <li class="active"><a href="#loadavg_ul" data-toggle="collapse"
                          aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle"> <i
                            class="fas fa-truck-loading"></i> Load Avg.</a>
                         <ul  class="collapse list-unstyled" id="top_ul"  
                                      th:each="loadAvgStatDir:${loadAvgStatDirs}">
                        <a href="#"><li  class="sidebar_li_item" 
                               th:text="${loadAvgStatDir}">loadAvgStatDir</li></a>
                         </ul> 
                     </li>
                     <li>
                      ...
                     </li>
```

I am quite new to thymleaf so could be making some dummy mistake.

I am getting this:

[image: Screenshot 1]

I am expecting to see all these:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Also, I am using this template for the partially collapsible sidebar - https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar

**UPDATE:**

Found the error in the code - **the th:each part should be in anchor tag encapsulating List-item tag.**

Comment: If it works without the collapsible classes, it may be because you are reusing the same `id` in each loop -- `id="top_ul"`.  Have you tried assigning a unique id during the loop?

Comment: Hi @Metroids, yes I am using a unique id for each loop, like id="loadavg_ul", id="netstat_ul" etc.  Also, If I use indexes (like  th:text="${topStatDirs[0]}" etc) then also it is working but since content is dynamic I cant use that approach.

Comment: I'm talking about something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66909052/4126893 -- where you use an expression to make sure your `id`s are unique.  You are using the same `id` on each subelement.

Comment: Hi @Metroids, I managed to fix the issue without changing much. When I checked the generated source code in the browser, there were X numbers of <ul>, followed by single <li>, but I wanted a single <ul> with X <li> inside it (because of the template I was using), so I moved the "th:each" part in the anchor tag (encapsulating <li>).. and it worked!!!  Not sure if I should delete this question or leave it open.